# _tmain() почему такое название?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Почему такое имя дает VS, исполняющей функции, в консольном приложении?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Всё просто.

Для не-Unicode-программ используется соответствующее стандарту имя `main` и список параметров `int argc, char* argv[]`.

Для Unicode-программ список параметров в MSVC выглядит как `int argc, wchar_t* argv[]`, и во избежание конфликтов с исходниками и компиляторами, соответствующими стандарту, функция называется `wmain`.

Для программ, которые могут компилироваться и в Unicode-, и в не-Unicode-режиме, список аргументов выглядит как `int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]`, где макрос `_TCHAR` определён как `char` или `wchar_t` в зависимости от значения макроса `_UNICODE`. Таким образом, нужно третье имя для функции. Так и было придумано имя `_tmain`.

Всё это, конечно, требует некоторой магии компоновщика, который должен уметь определить entry point не только в функции `main`, как по стандарту, а и в функциях `wmain`/`_tmain`.

Если вы уверены, что вам не нужно Unicode-приложение, вы можете переименовать функцию в `main` и дать ей список аргументов `int argc, char* argv[]`, чтобы соответствовать стандарту. Или если вы твёрдо решили, что ваша программа будет запускаться лишь под линейкой WinNT/XP/7 (а не Win95/98), вы можете остановиться на Unicode-варианте и переименовать функцию в `wmain` (соответственно, аргументы должны быть `int argc, wchar_t* argv[]`).

---

Запоздалое уточнение (спасибо @alexolut): Согласно [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx), `_tmain` определяется в `<tchar.h>` при помощи `#define` как `main` или `wmain`, так что в вашей программе всё равно будет либо `main`, либо `wmain`.

(И да, вы можете опустить параметры, или добавить третий параметр `envp`, или задекларировать возвращаемый тип `void`.)

Comment: Вот ещё обсуждение, откуда взялась (ещё одна) альтернативная пара `WinMain`/`wWinMain`: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/03/6644060.aspx

Comment: отличная статья! Спасибо

Comment: @gecube: Пожалуйста! Я вообще неровно дышу ко всему the old new thing.

Comment: Аргументы всё-таки не обязательны. Ещё любопытно, что при одновременном присутствии `main`/`wmain` точкой входа будет `main`. А чтобы работал вариант `_tmain` нужно так или иначе подключить `<tchar.h>`. Т.к. `_tmain` это всего лишь `#define`, который разворачивается в `main` или `wmain`.

Comment: @alexolut: По поводу `#define` дополнил ответ, спасибо! По поводу выбора между `main`/`wmain`, раз уж линкер поддерживает нестандартную точку входа, то ему придётся делать выбор. При наличии `main` он, понятно, должен соответствовать стандарту, т. к. теоретически конформная стандарту программа имеет право содержать `wmain`.